# DOMException while copying text to clipboard in javascript

Tags: javascript, clipboard, encode

I am trying to make a simple encoder in javascript, and copying the output to the clipboard, but the code gives an error.

I tried this code:

```js
function encode() {
  let alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890-=!@#$%^&*()_+[];'/.,'{}|:~";
  const a_list = alphabet.split('');
  const m_list = prompt("message: ").split('');
  let return_message = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < m_list.length; i++) {
    let current_letter = m_list[i];
    let translated_letter = a_list[a_list.indexOf(current_letter) + 5];
    return_message += translated_letter;
  }
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(return_message);
}
encode()
```

but the console gives this error:

> Error: DOMException {INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1, DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2, HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3, WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4, INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5, …}

I host the server in replit.
When I try to do an alert with the encoded words, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.clipboard.writeText` requires a [transient user activation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation). That is why it works when you click on an alert box.

> Transient user activation is required. The user has to interact with the page or a UI element in order for this feature to work.
>
> The "clipboard-write" permission of the Permissions API is granted automatically to pages when they are in the active tab.

https://devdocs.io/dom/clipboard/writetext